# Which privileges for MySQL extended status?

Tags: mysql, permissions

If I want to execute "SHOW STATUS" within MySQL or use "mysqladmin extended-status" on command line with a non-root user, which privileges would this user then need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the MySql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html):

> This statement does not require any privilege. It requires only the
>   ability to connect to the server.

Comment: Ohh shame on me, a normal user without any privileges can do it :)